# The getter 'length' was called on null was called on a preexisting json

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json file saved in my assets folder, all i wanted to do is just display the json file in my Listview.Builder which I'm successfully getting it displayed, but the problem here is before the App is getting initialized I'm getting the following error in the console not on the mobile screen.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<String>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (11766): _FutureBuilderState<String>#ef73b):
I/flutter (11766): The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter (11766): Receiver: null
I/flutter (11766): Tried calling: length
```

And this is my code

```
class _OfficeScreenState extends State<OfficeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            var showData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
            return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(showData[index]['OfficeName']),
                    subtitle: Text(showData[index]['Pincode']),
                  );
                },
              itemCount: showData.length,
            );
          }, future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/json/office.json'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ```if (snapshot.hasData) return ListView.builder()``` you must check first if the data has data..the problem on your case is your calling ```showData.length``` when its not yet filled.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `hasData` check before rendering the list

```dart
if(snapshot.hasData) {
    // build the list
} 
...
// build the wait message
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Future element before Builder. This can point to a Future method, which supply the data

Add an if condition like if(snapshot.data!=null), then provide the code, else return a CircularProgressIndicator widget

Answer (score 0):

Check first snapshot.hasData, if not Show some loading widget

```
class _OfficeScreenState extends State<OfficeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            var showData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(showData[index]['OfficeName']),
                    subtitle: Text(showData[index]['Pincode']),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: showData.length,
              );
            } else
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
          },
          future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
              .loadString('assets/json/office.json'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```